# Is there some way to make the "color" command work in PHP CLI?

Tags: php, windows, cmd, terminal, background-color

If I type `color 12` in `cmd.exe` and press `Enter`, it changes the entire background color for the entire terminal window.

If I run `shell_exec('color 12');` in `test.php`, nothing happens.

I'm not talking about ANSI color codes which can change the background of text columns. I already do those, but that still leaves huge gaps all over the window which are not colorized.

There's probably some technical reason why this only works from a "manual" cmd.exe window, but knowing what exactly that detail is doesn't help me solve the issue. Is there really no way to change the cmd.exe's *background color* (not ANSI color code background!) from PHP CLI?

Not talking about manually changing any settings in menus. It must be a terminal command that works when executed in PHP CLI.

Comment: shell_exec starts a new shell, it doesn't control the one from which you launched the PHP script. But the shell is launches will be in the background, without any visual representation.

Comment: @ADyson So... what is the answer? Is there some way?

Comment: To be honest I don't know. I was just pointing out the flaw in the shell_exec approach. if I knew the answer I'd have answered

Comment: @ADyson Does it really "start a new shell", though? I always thought it just executed a command on the existing terminal.

Comment: No, it doesn't, it starts a new instance

Comment: `color` is an internal cmd.exe command that uses the console API to modify the background and foreground color of the console's active screen buffer. You can call the API itself if PHP has FFI capability (like ctypes and cffi in Python). Otherwise you need a way to execute a `cmd.exe /c` command line attached to the current console, like `system("color 12")` in C. It's a new shell instance, but what matters is that it's attached to the same console. The shell and the console/terminal are not even remotely the same thing. The console is hosted by conhost.exe or openconsole.exe.

Comment: @ErykSun PHP does indeed have FFI. But I cannot figure out how to use it. How would I make it execute the color command as you say?

Comment: To implement CMD's `color` command, get the screen buffer handle via `GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)`. Get the screen buffer size via [`GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolescreenbufferinfo). Fill the screen, starting at the (0, 0) origin, with the desired text attributes via [`FillConsoleOutputAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/fillconsoleoutputattribute). Finally, set the attributes for new text via [`SetConsoleTextAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoletextattribute).

Comment: Or forget all that, and just find a way to spawn `cmd.exe /c "color 12"` attached to the current console.

Comment: @ErykSun Isn't that exactly the problem? I mean, that's what I'm essentially asking how to do?

Comment: The question assumes that cmd.exe is the console, but it's just a console client process, no different in that regard from php.exe, powershell.exe, python.exe or any program that's attached to a console. I described the way cmd.exe implements its `color` command using the console API. If PHP has FFI capability,  then you can do the same from within the php.exe process, but it's not trivial to implement. Otherwise you need to create a child cmd.exe process that's attached to the current console, such as by calling C `system("color 12")` via FFI, from msvcrt.dll or ucrtbase.dll.

Comment: Also, I don't know what PHP provides as standard library functions, but I doubt that `shell_exec` is all it offers. To not offer a function that can simply run an executable in the current console session would be a huge oversight. Python has several ways to do this, such as `subprocess.call`, `os.system`, and `os.spawnl`, so for a language to offer *no way* to do this would leave me speechless.